# How to prevent multirow in longtable from overflowing into subsequent table lines?

Tags: longtable, multirow

I have a `longtable` that currently looks like this:

[image: longtable with unnecessary spacing]

I would like to make the table more compact and get rid of the empty spaces highlighted in yellow. I've tried to achieve this by wrapping the contents of the last column into a `multirow` command, but while the empty space is now gone, the `multirow` contents do not seem to add their height into the total row height calculation so that the contents now reach into the cell below it and even into the space below the table:

[image: compact but overflowing longtable]

Is there a way to automatically adjust the height of the `longtable` row (if possible while still allowing for page breaks)? I'd like to avoid having to patch the tables with manual spacing since there would be hundreds of rows to adjust...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[longtable]{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{1cm}p{3cm}|l|p{7cm}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|p{4cm}|}{\textbf{Lorem ipsum}} & \textbf{Dolor} & \textbf{Sit amet}
  \endhead
  \hline
  A-1.1 & Consectetur & X & \multirow{2}{=}{%
    Proin vitae blandit enim. Ut a cursus felis, ac ullamcorper lorem. Donec dignissim 
    rutrum dui, in suscipit odio. Morbi quis scelerisque sem. Nullam condimentum massa 
    eget nisi rutrum, nec vulputate lorem dictum. 
  }\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|p{3.5cm}|}{\emph{(Nullam porta, tortor ut accumsan ultrices.)}} & & \\
  \hline
  \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots
  \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You not need to use `multirow` cells. Try the following: `\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|l|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Lorem ipsum}  & \textbf{Dolor} & \textbf{Sit amet}
\endhead
\hline
A-1.1 Consectetur

(\lipsum[1][1])
    & X & %\multirow{2}{=}{%
\lipsum[1][2-6] \\  \hline
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots    \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Zarko The first two columns are separated in order to keep the identifiers and texts aligned - your version breaks that. Also, it's really hard to understand what you're trying to do because the line breaks get lost in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Let me convert my comment to an answer (for better visibilities of table format:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document} 
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|l|p{7cm}|} 
    \hline 
\textbf{Lorem ipsum}    & \textbf{Dolor} & \textbf{Sit amet}\\ 
    \endhead 
    \hline 
A-1.1 Consectetur  

(\lipsum[1][1])         & X             & \lipsum[1][2-6]   \\  
    \hline \ldots       & \ldots        & \ldots            \\ 
    \hline 
\end{longtable} 
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

However, if for some reasons like to have `multicolumn` and `multirow` cells, than a good option is to use `tabularray` package.

**Edit:**
Package `tabularray` (so far) offer three kinds of tables:

- `tblr`, as more powerful replacement for `tabular` as well `tabularx` tables
- `talltblr`, as more powerful replacement for `threeparttable`,  `threeparttablex` tables
- `longtblr` as more versatile `longtable`, `xltabular`

An example, which demonstrate, how you can write your table code, is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Long table},
label= {tab:longtblr}]%
            {vline{1,3-Z},
             colspec = {Q[l,wd=4em] Q[l,wd=4cm] c X[h,j]},
             column{1} = {font=\bfseries}, 
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowhead=1
            }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{c} Lorem ipsum 
        &           & Dolor     &   Sit amet                \\
    \midrule
A-1.1   & Consectetur
                    & X         & \SetCell[r=2]{j} 
                                  \lipsum[1][2-6]           \\
\SetCell[c=-2]{h,j,wd=4cm+4em+2\tabcolsep, font=\normalfont}  \lipsum[1][1]
        &           &           &                           \\
    \midrule
A-1.123   & Consectetur
                    & Y         & \SetCell[r=2]{j}
                                  \lipsum[1][7-9]           \\
\SetCell[c=-2]{h,j,wd=4cm+4em+2\tabcolsep, font=\normalfont}  \lipsum[1][3-4]
        &           &           &                           \\
    \midrule
\ldots  & \ldots    & \ldots    & \ldots                    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I have a recent version of TeXlive installed, the package tabularray does not appear to be available.

Comment: @vwegert, it is available on CTAN. You need to install yourself (by help of some TeXlive tool). Recent version is 2021P, but this month can be scheduled new version.